# Something Happens AS something else is happening

Tags: grammar, as

do we only use **Past** **sentences** for sentences like 
“Kate slipped as she was getting off the bus” ?

- Kate slips as she is getting off the bus.

is it correct to use this type if sentences for present/future sentence?

- Kate slips as she gets off the bus.

Or this would be the correct usage for present tense.

Answer (score 0):

> Kate slipped as she was getting off the bus.

describes an accident.  It is fine in a past tense construction but not in present tense or in a construction to describe a possible future occurrence.  A possible exception is in writing a fiction, where some writers prefer the present tense for more immediacy.

In general writing, to use the present tense or to describe a possible future occurrence, a different context may be possible:

> Kate **always focuses** (or **would always focus**) on her phone as she gets off a bus.

Comment: Okay I’ll use that structure accordingly